# Deleted regedit files

Tags: windows-7, desktop-computer, regedit

This is gonna sound stupid but I accidentally deleted some regedit files. I tried to restart my computer. Soon after, I realized I could’ve restored my system to an earlier time. After restarting, I’m left with a blank screen and my mouse cursor. I tried running bios to no avail. How do I get my system running so I can restore it??

Comment: Boot from an install disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you do not have a backup of your registry. Few of us do. And the registry changes by the minute as you use your system.

Accordingly, there is no practical way to get it going in the state it is.

Boot from a bootable USB Key and recover your data to a USB Hard Drive or high capacity Key.

Then reinstall Windows and your Apps and restore your data.

Comment: I honestly don’t care about the data on that computer since there wasn’t much on it. I’d just like to access it, even in a factory condition. Is there a quicker way to reset my computer or would I still need the USB key?

Comment: You need the Windows 7 DVD in order to reinstall Windows,

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Comment: I trust you will acknowledge my answer by click on one the the appropriate buttons in the answer